# Wi-Fi disconnects frequently on lubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, lubuntu, network-manager, internet

Wi-Fi connects and disconnects frequently. When i turn on the computer, the wifi works and I can be connected to it for about 40 seconds, after that it loses connection and the wifi networks stop appearing and the wifi board turns off. I have tried turning off power saving, after doing that, it worked for about 1 minute (i could access the internet), but the same issue kept happenning. The Wi-Fi board I have is a Fenvi ax200.

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`. Look at your WiFi MTU with `ip link`. It should be 1492 not 1500.

Comment: @waltinator MTU should not be 1492. That applies for PPPoE links. Wifi does not use PPPoE. If your belief in that MTU should *always* be 1492 on WiFi, why haven't the Kernel developers configured it to be 1492B?